# Importing matrix from text file to PDL

Tags: perl, perl-module, pdl

Rather than creating the matrix using PDL, I would like to know ways to use existing matrix in TAB delimited file in PDL.
I wish to perform math operations on that matrix.
I tried math operations on **randomly created matrix** in situ but I have no idea if it is possible to import matrix from text files.

```
use PDL;
$a = zeroes 5,5;
$b = xvals $a;
print $b;
```

Here , 5X5 matrix with zeros was created for trial. I would be interested in external matrix not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PDL::IO::Misc::rcols`:

Input data:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
```

code:

```
use PDL;

my $x = rcols( 'foo.dat', [] );

print $x;
```

Result:

```
% perl foo.pl

[
 [ 1  6]
 [ 2  7]
 [ 3  8]
 [ 4  9]
 [ 5 10]
]
```